# Android | Using .Class file compiled on Linux , Window

Tags: android, jar, saxon

My ultimate objective is to make use of Saxon [SaxOn](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/) On Android, got its class file form the give link ( .JAR ) and hangup on following,

1 -- These class files i am not able to use directly on Android, it says class not found , (.net.sf.saxon.transformimpl)its showing run time exceptation,

2 -- By seeing above error my conclusion was, it seems i need to port Saxon on Android, but not able to digest, as Android also Java based and these are Java libraries

3 -- We believe Saxon Compiled on JVM and Android having DVM probably this was causing problem,

4 -- I did a simple experiment , Implemented one hello world library ( .JAR ) file in linux, and import it into the Android,

5 -- Now using this class file ( Hello World) Android program again says same error ( class not foud),

In Summary :

Is it not possible to make use of existing JAR file ( Through compiled on any platform ) directly into the Android ,

If its possible, then what would be the approach,

and can anyone through light on using Saxon On Android

Thanks for looking at the question,

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse, you have to add the jar file to the build path.  Then you should be able to simply use `import com.example.ClassName` to import your classes.

To add your jar in Eclipse:

1. Select "Properties" by right-clicking on your project name.
2. Choose "Java Build Path" from the list.
3. Push the "Add Jars" button, selecting the Jar file from your system.
4. Add the imports needed for the classes that you use from that Jar file.
5. Recompile.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We use a pre-compiled Java jar file in one of our Android apps and this is how we did it.  You may have issues if the Java Jar file you use makes references to other Java classes that aren't supported on Android, like javax, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Saxon is not currently supported on Android. It's something we would like to do if we can find the time, but there are many calls on our time and we have limited resources. I don't think there are any insuperable problems in doing it, but quite a few minor changes would be needed, and it would be a challenge to do it without forking the code, which is obviously undesirable.

Comment: Thanks Michael , but we were able to resolve it some part of Saxon , in fact, i can able to say that, now saxon partially working on the android ( Whatever we needed). surely we will not violate licenses and  follow all standard procedure,

Comment: Correct: you're not violating any licenses by running Saxon on Android, but you're on your own, in that we won't be fixing any bugs or removing any restrictions or giving you any help: thaht's what we mean by "unsupported".